# Transforming between two encodings for Boolean vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

There is a problem in the book by: Stephen Boyd, Lieven Vandenberghe, titled: Introduction to Applied Linear Algebra, on page #$38$, Q. $1.7$.

Transforming between two encodings for Boolean vectors. A Boolean n-vector is one
for which all entries are either 0 or 1. Such vectors are used to encode whether each
of n conditions holds, with ai = 1 meaning that condition i holds. Another common
encoding of the same information uses the two values −1 and +1 for the entries. For
example the Boolean vector (0, 1, 1, 0) would be written using this alternative encoding
as (−1, +1, +1, −1). Suppose that x is a Boolean vector with entries that are 0 or 1, and
y is a vector encoding the same information using the values −1 and +1. Express y in
terms of x using vector notation. Also, express x in terms of y using vector notation.

Problem wants two boolean representations to be expressed in terms of each other, using vector notation. The first one is having: $0,1$ & the other $-1,1$. But, out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $\bf x$ has $0/1$ values and $\bf y$ expresses $\bf x$'s entries as $-1/1$ values as indicated in the problem. Take a look at $\bf y+1$, where $\bf 1$ denotes a vector consisting of all ones.

Comment: So, the boolean character of data (encoding) ensures that while $-1+1=0$; still $1+1=1$. I.e., the data is $\mod 2$. So, the data property of being $\mod (2)$ is in usage here. I hope that for other data, such transformation is not possible. If yes, kindly give an example.

Comment: @jiten Actually, mod 2 the value of $1+1$ is zero. I don't think considerations of mod 2 are in play when people try to represent boolean values. The point of this exercise is that the transformation from one encoding to the other is invertible -- you can get the first encoding from the second, and vice versa. Other encodings are legitimate as long as True and False receive different values. The two encodings you are looking at are the most frequently used.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two symbols in one encoding $a,b$ that corresponds to another two symbol $w,d$ in another encoding.

You just have to construct the line that connect $(a,w)$ to $(b,d)$.

Here $0$ is being mapped to $-1$ and $1$ is being map to $1$, we want to connect $(0,-1)$  and $(1,1)$.

$$y=2x-1$$

for each component, now you just need to write them in vector format.

Comment: Seems like there is also possible an alternate representation by having two column vectors  with the first one of $(0,-1)$ for $x$ values, while the second is $(1,1)$ for $y$ values. Need to solve to get a common point of intersection. But, what should be the rhs of the equation $c_1c_2X = b$, with column vector $X = (x,y)$.

Comment: no idea what you are describing. (remark: my meeting begins in 5 minutes, slow response), common point of intersection?

Comment: You are stating that need map $0\rightarrow -1$ for $x$ values, and $1\rightarrow 1$ for $y$ values. So, there can be two column vectors for $x,y$ values. The first column vector is multiplied by $x$, while the second is by $y$. Alternatively, can view this approach as two rows with first row having $0x +1y$ on the lhs, while the second row having $-1x +y$ on the lhs. Need know the rhs of this representation (say, by matrix approach of two row vectors: $AX= B$, with $X$ being a column vector $(x,y)$).

Comment: Please see my other post at: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3651092/424260

Comment: If $B$ is unknown, move it to the left hand side and solve for the homogeneous linear system. But again, this is not the right tool to use even if it works.