# Finding number of occurrences in a Boolean vector, or a portion thereof.

Tags: linear-algebra

There is a problem in the book by: Stephen Boyd, Lieven Vandenberghe, titled: Introduction to Applied Linear Algebra, on page #$38$, Q. $1.9$.

Symptoms vector. 
A $20$-vector $s$ records whether each of $20$ different symptoms is present in a medical patient, with $s_i = 1$ meaning the patient has the symptom and $s_i = 0$
meaning she does not. 
Express the following using vector notation.
(a) The total number of symptoms the patient has.
(b) The patient exhibits five out of the first ten symptoms.

(a) There seems no notation except to employ multiplication by a Boolean row vector of all $1$'s, denoted by $w^T$. Now, can express result vector $r$ in the form $r = w^Ts$.
$$r = w^Ts, w^T= \begin{pmatrix} 1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1 \end{pmatrix}$$ which will be a numeric value, for $s$ being a column vector of size $20$.

I hope that as the $s$ vector is a collection of different attributes for a patient; so should be preferably a row vector. But for our need require it to be a column vector. 
Also, $w$ could be a row vector without need to take transpose.

Alternatively, if reverse the ordering to $r=sw$, then $s$ can be row vector and $w$ a column vector.

(b) Need split $w^T$ in two parts of $10$ consecutive elements each. But, not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my part $b$, if you have to construct a vector of size $20$, then  consider vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^{20}$, $$v_j = \begin{cases} 1 &, j \le 10 \\ 0 &, j > 10\end{cases}$$

perform dot product with $s$ and examine if it is equal to $5$. (or greater than $5$, depending on the interpretation of the question).

In partice, we would of course truncate $s$ at the $10$ positions and just sum the first part to be more efficient.